# Can you use Sidecar with 5G only to connect Macbook Pro to iPad Pro M1 devices reliably for work

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, wifi, apple-silicon, sidecar

I am using the 13" Macbook Pro M1 and considering getting a iPad Pro 12.9" M1 to establish a portable dual screen for work. So I would add the Tmobile 5G plan on the iPad and do not want to connect to wifi on the road.

Can I use the 5G from my iPad for both devices and get dual screen sidecar working reliably for work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidecar uses a wired or direct wireless connection. When using wireless there is a restriction against creating a mobile hotspot, but this restriction would not apply to a wired Sidecar configuration.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210380

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204023

Comment: just a note from my continued use, the Apple ID has to be the same. So if I have a work laptop with different Apple ID, I can't connect as sidecar.